# .htaccess to redirect specific subdirectory into querystring parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Need an `.htaccess` to do the following and I can't get it to work:

Redirect any url ending in `/recordings/` to `?recordings`

For example:

```
www.mysite.com/example-product-one/recordings/
```

becomes

```
www.mysite.com/example-product-one/?recordings
```

Or,

```
www.mysite.com/products/category/three/recordings
```

becomes

```
www.mysite.com/products/category/three/?recordings
```

Suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction... this is what ended up working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule /recordings/$ %{REQUEST_URI}../?recordings [L,R=301]
```